# PDO multiple queries in php /sql

Tags: php, sql

I have the following code.  I am grabbing values from a form, and using those values to try to update "customers" and "workorder".  The "name" value will be duplicate across the customers and workorder table.  I keep on getting the error "number of bound variables does not match number of tokens".  I am totally new to using PDO, and am unsure on how to proceed.  Any ideas?

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "UPDATE customers  set name = ?, email = ?, mobile =? WHERE id = ?; UPDATE workorder set name = ?;";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($name,$email,$mobile,$id));
Database::disconnect();
header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: You have 5 '?' placeholders but only 4 variables in your execute statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 variables here:

```
$q->execute(array($name,$email,$mobile,$id));
```

Should be 5:

```
$q->execute(array($name,$email,$mobile,$id, $name));
```